# c# datagrid splitting using character "|"

Tags: datagrid, using, split

I have a text file having these inside:

test | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 0

i am making a program with a data grid and im having problems splitting the rows because of the character "|". Does anyone know a solution for this ? my code below doesn't seem to work:

```
             foreach( string data in strArray )
             {
                 string[] textData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fName);
                 string[] storedData = strArray[0].Split("|");   

                 for(int i=1; i < textData.Length; i++)
                 {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textData[i].Split(','));
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = data;
                     j++;
                 }                                  
             }
```

im getting the error "Cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The separator argument of Split() must be `char`s, not a string: replace `Split("|")` with `Split('|')`.